# Unable to remove old daemon and related files in MAC using install4j

Tags: windows, macos, install4j

We are using install4j for the installer. We are using default unistallation of install4j and Delete files and directories action. whenever we are installing new version, old directory and daemon needs to be removed. It is working well in Windows machine, but not working MAC especially in MAC 10.11 and 10.12. When we restart the system in MAC, eventhough the directories are not removing but old daemon is stopping. So please help us on the following.
1. How to remove old installed files and daemon in MAC without restart using on re installation using install4j

Comment: Please make the sequence of what is happening and what you expect to happen clearer. Generally, removing files can be a problem on Windows because of file locking, but on macOS this is not a problem.

Comment: We followed the similar steps as windows and it is working as expected in windows but on mac 10.11 and mac 10.12 daemon keeps running until re-start

Comment: Removing files is also creating problem in mac 10.11 and 10.12

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make it any clearer. Removing files on macOS is not a general problem, it must be something specific to your project. You would have to isolate your specific condition and report a reproducible test case.